# Javascript: onload function called twice

Tags: javascript, onload

```
Transition.start = function(){
    for(var j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
         console.log("FOR LOOP");
         (function(){
             console.log("INNER Function");
             var image = new Image();
             image.src = path + Config.imgName[j] + ".jpg";
             image.onload = function () {

                 console.log("GONE");
                 clearImages[source].push(image);
                 console.log(image);
             };
         })();
     }
}
```

In this on console "FOR LOOP"  and "INNER Function" is printed 6 times, but "GONE" is printed 12 times. I am not able to figure out the reason for this. I want to run the body of onload also 6 times.

and `Transition.start` is called from `onDocumentKeyDown` listener like this

```
function onDocumentKeyDown( event )
{
    if (keyPressed == 38) //up arrow
        Transition.start();
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where this function gets called

Comment: I think console.log(image) is calling the "image.onload" and hence the "GONE" is being print more number of times.

Comment: Did you try `console.trace()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the the source of the problem. Actually `image.onload` is called everytime the image is rendered in the browser. Actually I once image is loaded I was storing it in `clearImages` so that if in future the image is required then it can be taken directly from that array, so if the image is required in future then it is loaded from the `clearImages` array but again the onload function will be called.

So I **solved this** thing by doing `image.onload = null` inside `onload` function itself